# Unable to transfer file from Amazon EC2 to S3

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to transfer files from EC2 (running ubuntu) to S3 using s3cmd command line .. however it gives the following warning 
([Errno 32] Broken pipe)

The file size is 50 Mb ..

What is it that i am doing wrong .. Is there any other option available to achieve the same

Comment: if you don't mind coding a bit you can use the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/). Uploading a file is quite easy, just create your AmazonS3 object and do something [like this](https://github.com/pablopareja/BioinfoAWS/blob/master/src/main/java/com/era7/bioinfo/bioinfoaws/s3/S3FileUploader.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the bucket you're uploading to exist? The `broken pipe` error could indicate you're using a bucket that doesn't exist and couldn't be successfully created for whatever reason. Log into the AWS console for your account and check that you have that bucket, or just create it in the AWS console.